# why apache response very slow when traffic goes high?

Tags: server, apache2, mysql

I have a news android application which is workes on API as backend (admin panel) on symfony (PHP Frameworks).

When i send push notification API (Firebase) to my user my server response very slow. after some times my server works properly.

My application have - 10,000 active users

Server Details --

- 2vCPU and 8GB RAM (On Google Cloud)
- Operating System - Ubuntu 18.04
- Web server - Apache2
- Database - MySQL
- PHP version - PHP 7.0 (Because
  my application does not support higher php version)

Apache mpm_prefork_module configuration details

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers             20
    MinSpareServers          20
    MaxSpareServers          80
    ServerLimit              4000
    MaxRequestWorkers        35000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

All the apache and MySQL's settings are default.

Here is my Apache web server configuration (SSL)

https://ibb.co/pdWptkn

Apache Error Logs --

```
[Thu Sep 03 05:49:38.326292 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3102] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 03 05:49:38.543477 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18326] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 03 05:49:38.543522 2020] [core:notice] [pid 18326] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

This is my Highest usage of memory
[Check Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa0cy.png)

https://ibb.co/w6LP7r6

Please guys give me any solution for this issue.

Thanks in Advance.